# margin-bottom attribute not working

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

**I have css code:**

```
.dropdown-menu {
  position:absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  display: none;
  float: left;
  min-width: 160px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  margin: 2px 0 0;
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  border-radius: 6px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.175);
  box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.175);
  background-clip: padding-box;
}
.arrow {
position:absolute;
margin-bottom: 50px;
margin-left: 50px;
width: 0;
height: 0;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 0 5px 8.7px 5px;
border-color: transparent transparent #007bff transparent;
line-height: 0px;
_border-color: #000000 #000000 #007bff #000000;
_filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Chroma(color='#000000');
}
```

**HTML code:**

```
       <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li class="arrow"></li>
              <li><a href="#">Credit History</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Purchased Content</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Access logs</a></li>
        </ul>
```

`

The `margin-bottom: 50px;` from `arrow` class will move my arrow down. If I put `margin-top: 50px;`, my arrow will still go down. I am trying to put that arrow upper outside the dropdown menu.

Can anyone tell me why my arrow does not go up please? Thank you very much!

**Later edit: I updated the question.**

FIDDLE [here](https://jsfiddle.net/imarketsg/zb5Lx5fL/)

Comment: could you please reproduce the issue in a fiddle or so..

Comment: Or at least add the HTML to the question too.

Comment: Updated with fiddle.

Comment: I am trying to put that arrow upper outside the dropdown menu.

Comment: which part outside the menu.you want to position the arrow at the buttom center? on top center?

Comment: Can you put the arrow outside the <ul>? And play with the padding-bottom you're using...

<div class="arrow"></div>

Comment: The arrow must be outside the dropdown list. Like a pointer to the button I  pressed.

Comment: If I put the arrow outside the `<ul>` it will always be visible. It must be visible only when dropdown active.

Comment: @repzero top right (outside the dropdown).

Comment: okay see my approach....am i on the right track?

Comment: okay..you may want to take out position:absolute and top:100% and put it into the newly create menu_options container..everything will work as expect...see edit done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want something like this

```css
#menu_options {
position: absolute;
/*top: 100%;*/

}
.dropdown-menu {
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  float: left;
  min-width: 160px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  margin: 2px 0 0;
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  border-radius: 6px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.175);
  box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.175);
  background-clip: padding-box;
}

.arrow {
  position:relative;
  top:3px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 5px 8.7px 5px;
  border-color: transparent transparent #007bff transparent;
  line-height: 0px;
  _border-color: #000000 #000000 #007bff #000000;
  _filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Chroma(color='#000000');
}
```

```html
<div id='menu_options'>
<li class="arrow"></li>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <li><a href="#">Credit History</a></li>
  <li class="divider"></li>
  <li><a href="#">Purchased Content</a></li>
  <li class="divider"></li>
  <li><a href="#">Access logs</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: With your code, the arrow will always be visible. Must be visible only when dropdown is active.That means the `<li class="arrow"></li>` must be in `<ul>`.

Comment: okay..you may want to take out position:absolute and top:100% and put it into the newly create menu_options container..everything will work as expect...see edit done

Comment: Although your code does not work for me, I will accept your answer, because thanks to you I found the solution.

Answer (score 1):

My solution which finally worked is:

**CSS code:**

```
    .dropdown-menu {
      position: absolute;
      display:none;
    /*  top: 100%;*/
      left: 0;
      z-index: 1000;
      float: left;
      min-width: 160px;
      padding: 5px 0;
      margin: 2px 0 0;
      list-style: none;
      font-size: 14px;
      background-color: #ffffff;
      border: 1px solid #cccccc;
      border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
      border-radius: 6px;
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.175);
      box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.175);
      background-clip: padding-box;
    }

.arrow {
  position:relative;
  left: 80%;
  bottom:13px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 5px 8.7px 5px;
  border-color: transparent transparent #fff transparent;
  line-height: 0px;
  _border-color: #000000 #000000 #fff #000000;
  _filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Chroma(color='#000000');
}
```

**HTML code:**

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
<li class="arrow"></li>
  <li><a href="#">Credit History</a></li>
  <li class="divider"></li>
  <li><a href="#">Purchased Content</a></li>
  <li class="divider"></li>
  <li><a href="#">Access logs</a></li>
</ul>
```

Thanks to @repzero.